# Simple form select displays wrong values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using Simple Form for rails 4, and I'm trying to display a form based on models using the `belongs_to` and `has_many` methods there. However, my models are overriding name conventions because I'm using a legacy DB:

```
class Almacen < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "CATALMA"
  self.primary_key = "COD_ALM"

  alias_attribute :COD_ZONA, :cod_zona
  alias_attribute :zona_id, :cod_zona

  belongs_to  :zona
  validates :NOM_ALM, presence: true

end

class Almacen < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "CATALMA"
  self.primary_key = "COD_ALM"

  alias_attribute :COD_ZONA, :cod_zona
  alias_attribute :zona_id, :cod_zona

  belongs_to  :zona
  validates :NOM_ALM, presence: true

end
```

In the form, the related part is this:

```
<%= f.association :zona %>
```

Butit displays the following values instead the names of "Zona"
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a [`to_s`](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2007/01/20/a-handy-use-of-to_s/) method in the `Zone` model, what returns name or something like name(i do not know what's the name of this column, assume it's `zone_name`).

```
class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    "The #{zone_name}"
    # attribute that return column name
  end
end
```

`<%= f.association :zona %>` use 2 columns in your table zone, `id` and if not provided second, it's used string representation of your model `"#<Zone:0x000000064e1e88>"`.

Other way is add more options to the `f.assocation(...)` method.

```
f.association :zone, label_method: :zone_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But, Is there any chance to use a Select2 instead?

Comment: What is the `Select2`?

Comment: I found interesting the fact of "The " string is included in that method, but is never displayed. Is it some kind of convention?

Comment: Yes you can use `select2` here, first you should add javascript files of `Select2` in the project, second, make a _manual_ iteration with all records  of the Zone model [snippet](https://gist.github.com/fishbullet/170eecc4e26bd52318b8), or play around [`options_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select), and initialize `Select2` with js. Sorry i do not understand _interesting the fact of_. Happy coding!

Comment: I mean in the method `to_s` `"The #{zone_name}"` only the desired value zone_name is displayed, but not "The". It's okay, but I just want to know why.

Comment: This is some _furry_ bug. I need a more related code to help you.